# Getting Ignite Exception in Kafka Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, ignite, apache-kafka-connect

I am running 3 servers and 1 client topology.

1 of the servers node is being run by kafka connector process.

client is not able to send any message to that kafka connector ignite node.

this is the exception

````
SEVERE: Failed to read message [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=0, topic=null, topicOrd=-1, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=null], buf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=4 lim=251 cap=32768], reader=DirectMessageReader [state=DirectMessageState [pos=0, stack=[StateItem [stream=DirectByteBufferStreamImplV2 [baseOff=140323292482432, arrOff=-1, tmpArrOff=0, valReadBytes=0, tmpArrBytes=0, msgTypeDone=false, msg=null, mapIt=null, it=null, arrPos=-1, keyDone=false, readSize=-1, readItems=0, prim=0, primShift=0, uuidState=0, uuidMost=0, uuidLeast=0, uuidLocId=0], state=0], null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]], protoVer=3, lastRead=false], ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=3, bytesRcvd=251, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=251, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1604581761046, hashCode=1782557810, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#139]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=4 lim=251 cap=32768], inRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=9, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=7, sentCnt=9, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=3f63a8d7-8964-4a4b-89c1-124d8eaba14a, consistentId=3f63a8d7-8964-4a4b-89c1-124d8eaba14a, addrs=ArrayList [127.0.0.1, 172.20.50.222], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:0, /172.20.50.222:0], discPort=0, order=4, intOrder=4, lastExchangeTime=1604581749120, loc=false, ver=8.7.10#20191227-sha1:c481441d, isClient=true], connected=false, connectCnt=1, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=2, pairedConnections=false], outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=9, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=7, sentCnt=9, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=3f63a8d7-8964-4a4b-89c1-124d8eaba14a, consistentId=3f63a8d7-8964-4a4b-89c1-124d8eaba14a, addrs=ArrayList [127.0.0.1, 172.20.50.222], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:0, /172.20.50.222:0], discPort=0, order=4, intOrder=4, lastExchangeTime=1604581749120, loc=false, ver=8.7.10#20191227-sha1:c481441d, isClient=true], connected=false, connectCnt=1, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=2, pairedConnections=false], outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=o.a.i.i.processors.metric.impl.AtomicLongMetric@69a257d1, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/172.20.52.38:54412, rmtAddr=/172.20.50.222:47100, createTime=1604581761046, closeTime=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=251, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=251, sndSchedTime=1604581761046, lastSndTime=1604581761046, lastRcvTime=1604581761046, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioTracerFilter [tracer=GridProcessorAdapter []], GridNioCodecFilter [parser=o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridDirectParser@1766eecd, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=false, markedForClose=false]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Invalid message type: -33
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoMessageFactory.create(GridIoMessageFactory.java:1106)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$5.create(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2407)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.direct.stream.v2.DirectByteBufferStreamImplV2.readMessage(DirectByteBufferStreamImplV2.java:1175)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.direct.DirectMessageReader.readMessage(DirectMessageReader.java:335)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoMessage.readFrom(GridIoMessage.java:270)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser.decode(GridDirectParser.java:89)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioCodecFilter.java:112)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter.onMessageReceived(GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter.java:87)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioServer.java:3681)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1360)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2472)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2239)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1880)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```
````

Comment: How are your messages serialized? How does Ignite want them to be serialized?

Answer (score 1):

Direct type -33 is `GridH2QueryRequest`.

Are you sure that your Kafka connector node has `ignite-indexing` in its classpath? Try adding it explicitly.

Comment: Yes. there was some jar extraction issue in our code. Found it. Thank you.